# Using Credit memo in magento community edition

Tags: magento

I have issued a credit memo in Magento Admin panel for an order, but I do not see how a customer can use this credit on the website? He cannot see it in the frontend either. How can this credit be managed by admin and/or by the customer?

Magento 1.8.0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Magento and not programming. Try http://magento.stackexchange.com instead


Answer (score 2, accepted):

When credit memo raised from admin, there is 2 option.

1. Online
2. Offline

If your integrated payment gateway support online, then that amount will credited into customer account.

If you integrated payment gateway doesn't support online, then Admin will go to Payment Gateway merchant account and manually transfer the fund to customer account.

Hope will help!